# Box2d libgdx won't accept BodyType as parameter

Tags: libgdx, box2d, game-engine

I think it's pretty much self explanatory

http://image.prntscr.com/image/b699a17ac7954732b18b275689425227.png
http://image.prntscr.com/image/86fc8d49e513402bac04f57483fbbe04.png

Sorry I could not upload pictures directly because I don't have enough reputation.

@Code added

Code from init method

```
terrainBodyUp=createPhysicsObjectFromGraphics(terrainAbove,
            new Vector2(terrainAbove.getRegionWidth()/2,480- terrainAbove.getRegionHeight()/2),
            BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody);
```

And my createPhysicsObjectFromGraphics method

```
private Body createPhysicsObjectFromGraphics(TextureRegion region,
                                             Vector2 position, BodyDef.BodyType bodyType) {
    BodyDef boxBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    boxBodyDef.type = bodyType;
    boxBodyDef.position.x = position.x/BOX2D_TO_CAMERA_;
    boxBodyDef.position.y = position.y/BOX2D_TO_CAMERA_;
    Body boxBody = world.createBody(boxBodyDef);
    PolygonShape boxPoly = new PolygonShape();
    boxPoly.setAsBox(region.getRegionWidth()/(2*BOX2D_TO_CAMERA_),
            region.getRegionHeight()/(2*BOX2D_TO_CAMERA_));
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = boxPoly;
    fixtureDef.density=1;
    fixtureDef.restitution=0.2f;
    boxBody.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    boxPoly.dispose();
    boxBody.setUserData(region);
    return boxBody;
}
```

Comment: is any more code possible?

Comment: I'll just go ahead and say that this probably has nothing to do with Box2D or libGDX

Comment: Well it makes no sense, I created the function and as you can see, as the parameter type I set BodyDef.BodyType but when I pass BodyDef.BodyType.Dynamic it produces error. If I directly assign BodyDef.BodyType.Dynamic inside the function, it works.

Comment: can you add a bit more of the surrounding code? it's hard to see what's going on

Comment: can you edit your question with adding actual code, someone might want to copy it, or read it from this page

Comment: may be you have own class or enum of type BodyDef ??

Comment: check type of terrainBodyUp ??

Comment: BodyDef.BodyType, @AbhishekAryan thanks!!

Comment: most welcome @Jumpman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Abishek Aryan for pointing me in the right direction. When I did "replace all" I changed accidentally data type and that caused me problems. So instead of using Body as data type I used BodyDef.BodyType

Answer (score 0):

Incompatible types error because createPhysicsObjectFromGraphics method return Body and you're assigning into terrainBodyUp variable which is type of BodyDef.BodyType.